# Parallelism in pairgrid plots

Tags: python, seaborn

For example, if I had a pairgrid plot like so:

```py
import matplotlib as plt
import seaborn as sns

p = sns.PairGrid(<some data>)  
p.map_upper(plt.scatter)
p.map_lower(sns.kdeplot)
p.map_diag(plt.hist)
```

Each of these `map_*` ops can run a while depending on the size and dimensionality of data, is there some way these can be parallelized?

Comment: I don't think it's possible because seaborn uses pyplot and its state machine. So the best you would be able to do is to create 3 figures, one with the upper, one with the lower and one with the diagonal. However, the function calls themselves should be rather quick compared to drawing the overall figure; have you compared the timings to see if you really would save anything?